# How to order by document chapter

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to create stored procedure for getting all the document titles from table, BUT it has to be ordered in a way that shows document chapters FIRST. I really don't know how to do this myself.

It would have to be ordered like this:

```
ID    Chapter      Description
1     0001-0299    Title
2     0001-0019    Title
3     0001         "some text"
4     0002         "some text"
.
.
.     0021-0039    Title
.     0021         "some text"
.     0022         "some text"
```

I think you get the point. Any chance someone can help? Thx for any help.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to use `ORDER BY` or `SELECT`?

Comment: I am saying I don't know how to write a proper ORDER BY. So far I am using ordering by ID, but I'll have a problem if anyone decides to delete a row.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you intend this:

```
select id, chapter, description
from t
order by left(chapter, 4),
         (case when chapter like '%-%' then 1 else 2 end),
         chapter;
```

This orders by the first four characters of the chapter, then by the chapters with the hyphens, and finally by the chapter itself.  If you need for the first two values to be in the "other" order, then:

```
select id, chapter, description
from t
order by left(chapter, 4),
         (case when chapter like '%-%' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when chapter like '%-%' then chapter end) desc,
         chapter asc;
```

Comment: 2nd case is exactly what I was looking for, works like a magic. Thank you SO MUCH Gordon! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will order by ID, then by Chapter.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'orderedDocuments', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE orderedDocuments;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE orderedDocuments
AS   
    SELECT
        ID, Chapter, Description
    FROM
        [Table Name]
    ORDER BY
         ID DESC
         ,Chapter DESC
GO
```

Comment: I am afraid I wasn't looking for this, but thx a lot for your time and effort :)